# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery

It seems I have found myself yet again in quite of a pickle. From what I understood via searching this issue was that if `var` is `int`, this error might occur. But as far as my amateur Javascript skills go, I did not detect such a thing in my completely [stolen code](http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/svbtle-image-uploading).

```
var createAttachment = function(file) {
    var uid  = [guava_uid, (new Date).getTime(), 'raw'].join('-');

    var data = new FormData();

    data.append('attachment[name]', file.name);
    data.append('attachment[file]', file);
    data.append('attachment[uid]',  uid);

    $.ajax({
      url: '/attachments',
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      type: 'POST',
    }).error(function(){
      console.log('could not upload');
    });

    var absText = '![' file.name + '](/attachments/' + uid + ')'; // <<< ERROR
    $('#editor textarea').insertAtCaret(absText);
};
```

`guava_uid` is defined before any of the code above as `guava_uid = "1";`, I tried it as `guava_uid = 1;` as well, but same result. All help is, as usual, appreciated.

Comment: Both answers below are incorrect. You need a plus sign between `'!['` and `file.name`.

Comment: Isn't it necessary to use `()` when creating a new `Date` object?

Comment: Correct! Such a tiny thing that completely slipped my mind. Thank you @RobW

Comment: @Teemu Yes, either `new Date().getTime()`, or (new Date).getTime()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/attachments',
  data: data,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  type: 'POST',
//            ^
//            should not be there
}).error(function(){
  console.log('could not upload');
});
```

And:

```
var absText = '![' file.name
//                ^
//            missing +
```

Comment: It doesn't *need* to be there, but it's also not technically invalid. I think only Internet Explorer had (perhaps still has) issues with trailing commas in object literals.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist IE makes it technically invalid ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var uid = ["guava_uid", (new Date).getTime(), 'raw'].join('-');
```

When i'm trying to use such code:

```
var uuid = some-uid-like-int
```

I've got the same error, but when i use uuid like a string - all okay.

Comment: I already mentioned in my question that whether an int or not, this didn't matter.